# Legend of CORINE land cover in ArcGIS 10.x layer file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, symbology, land-cover

I am looking for the legend of Land Cover (Corine Land Cover) for ArcsGIS 10.x. as a layer (.lyr) file.

I want to symbolize the classes without setting the RGB color values one by one; especially for level 2 and 3.

Comment: I just did a quick search and couldn't find a source for one. Related question (linking to others) about symbolizing based on the RGB values you have in table form: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123606/ However, I did just have an idea. I did a quick search of ArcGIS Online maps for the term CORINE and got a number of hits. Perhaps you could load up one of those to a map and then save the symbology to your own layer file as described at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122969/ Assuming one has the official symbology you want anyway.