# Where I can find ArcGIS online symbols to use in Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-online

I'd like to use this symbols:

[image]

In desktop ArcGIS.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question might help you out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122969/how-to-download-arcgis-online-symbology-to-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to follow the steps in [Downloading ArcGIS Online symbology to ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122969/how-to-download-arcgis-online-symbology-to-arcgis-desktop) to import the exact same A-Z symbols in your question.

[image: ArcMap Symbol Selector]

Comment: +1 because it is a step in right direction. I'd like to have the whole set though...